# Simple jQuery Image fade

Tags: jquery

Im trying to get this working but for some reason it's just not right. I want an image to fade to another image and just keep looping. It works in the fiddle but not on my wordpress site. I think it has to do with this piece. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/8ks9K/

jQ:

```
function cycleImages() {
    $('#portfolio_cycler').each(function() {
        var $active = $(this).find('.active');
        var $next = ($(this).find('.active').next().length > 0) ? $(this).find('.active').next() : $(this).find('img:first');
        $next.css('z-index', 2); //move the next image up the pile
        $active.fadeOut(1500, function() { //fade out the top image
            $active.css('z-index', 1).show().removeClass('active'); //reset the z-index and unhide the image
            $next.css('z-index', 3).addClass('active'); //make the next image the top one
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // run every 5s
    setInterval('cycleImages()', 5000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="feat_header">
    <div id="portfolio_cycler">
        <img class="active" src="http://baylor-personal-edge.com/wp-content/themes/striking/images/text_slide1.jpg" alt="You're used to a certain type of comfort" />
        <img src="http://baylor-personal-edge.com/wp-content/themes/striking/images/text_slide2.jpg" alt="You're physical should be no different" />        
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#portfolio_cycler{position:relative;}
#portfolio_cycler img{position:absolute;z-index:1}
#portfolio_cycler img.active{z-index:3}
#feat_header {
    background:#000;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:1px;
    height:23px;
    width:310px;
    z-index:9999;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: I see it transitioning, so you have functional code. Would you care to explain exactly what you need it to do?

Comment: What's the problem?  Your fiddle is working for me in Chrome.

Comment: seems to work fine. what browser do you use? what's *"not working"*?

Comment: As other have said, it appears to work fine in your example.

Comment: I'm adding this to a wordpress site and it's not working like in fiddle. "_I just see the main image_" When I debug it errors at the document ready function. I'm looking at the site in FF, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @Outlawsessy You have to understand that we can't just *know* how to fix the problem with nothing to work with. Could you please provide a link to the site where it is not working so we can debug the issue?

Comment: I updated my original post I hope this will help. Sorry I'm new and still learning.

Comment: set it up and show us in the wordpress site since that is what we are trying to diagnose.  It could be a js error on your site, conflicting css, or poorly formatted html.

Comment: Dave Cottrell's answer was spot on and solved my issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sd4gh/ Just to show you a nice loop.

Comment: Looks nice. Thanks for the advice Roko!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to keep in mind when developing in any framework that may be using jQuery or has plugins that may be using jQuery is to define a noConflict.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

just remember that you now need to change any instance of jQuery or $ to your newly defined $j

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('.example').fadeIn();
});
```

This may explain why its not working in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

i played with your fiddle and ended up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/8ks9K/8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // run every 5s
    var all = $('#portfolio_cycler img').hide();
    var idx = 0;
    $(all[idx]).show();
    setInterval(function cycleImages() {
        $(all[idx]).fadeOut('slow',function(){
            idx++;
            if( idx > all.length - 1 ) idx = 0;
                $(all[idx]).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }, 1000);
});​
```

i don't remember the problem, tho ;)